# Prove that if $T$ is one-to-one on $D$, then the set $T(D)$ is open

Tags: general-topology, analysis, manifolds

> Let $f$ and $g$ have continuous first-order partial derivatives on an open set $ D\subseteq\mathbf{R}^2 $ and let $T :D \to \mathbf{R}^2 $ be defined by
>
> $  T(u,v)=(f(u,v),g(u,v)). $
>
> Prove that if $ T $ is one-to-one on $D$, then the set $T(D)$ is open.

I need help ; I try to apply the inverse function theorem, but I can't see any connection between the injectivity and Jacobian matrix of $T$. Do i need to notice something completely different?

Comment: The Jacobian of $f$ need not be invertible, consider e.g. $f(u,v)=u^3$, $g(u,v)=v^3$. Hence, the inverse function theorem is not applicable in general. There is a (rather deep) result called **invariance of domain** (see Wikipedia), which states that if $f:U\to \Bbb{R}^n$ is continuous and injective with $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ open (note that the dimensions have to match), then $f$ is an open map. But if you do not know this theorem, I don't really know how you could solve this exercise.

Comment: @Phoemuex thanks for your comment .I think there exist solution to this problem without using invariance of domain .